# Installing coremltools on Python 3.6 Anaconda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, coremltools

I am trying to install `coremltools` following the instructions from [Converter tools for Core ML.](https://anaconda.org/derickl/coremltools):

```
(coreml) imac:~ henrik$ conda install -c derickl coremltools
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - coremltools -> python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

(coreml) imac:~ henrik$ python -V
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

As you can see, the environment is running Python 3.6.3, which should satisfy the 3.6* dependency. However, I keep getting the `UnsatisfiableError`.

I tried install `numpy` and `protobuf` in the environment, as they are listed as dependencies at [Apple's GitHub page for coremltools](https://github.com/apple/coremltools), but that did not change anything.

Comment: The problem is that, according to the error message, `coremltools` only runs on Python versions `2.7,<2.8.0a0`, so 3.6 is too new, you should install for python 2.x

Comment: It lists 3.6* also?

Comment: Yes, these are the two specifications that were found to be _in conflict_: __neither can live while the other survives__!

Comment: @ForceBru In that case, I misunderstood the (not very clear) error message. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the packaging information in [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coremltools) Apple is only supporting coremltools on Python 2.7.